# Como selecionar a partir do fim de um textBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Boa tarde galera!

Minha pergunta é simples e um pouco boba, mas esta me fazendo quebrar a cabeça.

Meu programa tem um textBox onde é gravado um log, a todo tempo novos dados (caracteres) são adicionados a este textBox. 
O que eu realmente me interessa neste log são seus últimos 7 caracteres. Eu estava pensando em usar o controle "textBox.selection" para seleciona-los, o problema é que não existe (até onde eu sei) um "SelectionEnd". O comando SelectionStart seta a partir de onde a seleção começa e o Length quantos caracteres essa seleção compreende, o que eu preciso é setar onde a seleção deve terminar (como eu disse, algo do tipo "SelectionEnd") e usar o "SelectionLength" para setar que é deste ponto até 7 caracteres atrás que a seleção deve compreender. Como posso fazer isso da maneira mais simples possível? Esses últimos 7 caracteres serão usados como nome do arquivo log no salvamento automático do mesmo.

Segue código referente ao salvamento automático. (onde meu problema está)

```
{
            CaptureInfo.CaptureFrame();

            textBox1.SelectionStart = 99999;
            textBox1.SelectionLength = -7;

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            caminhoImagemSalva = @"\\172.21.xxx.xxx\Impresa tal\Arquivo Digital\Arquivo de imagem atendimento\Guichê 04\"
                 + "Atendente 04"
                 + " "
                 + textBox1.SelectedText
                 + " "
                 + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString()
                 + "."
                 + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString()
                 + "."
                 + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()
                 + " as "
                 + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString()
                 + "h"
                 + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString()
                 + "min"
                 + ".jpg";
            picWebCam.Image.Save(caminhoImagemSalva, ImageFormat.Jpeg);


        }
```

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Se sabe o tamanho do texto no TextBox e quantos quer pegar é fácil saber qual é o start.

Comment: No caso em questão o textbox não tem um tamanho pré-definido.

Comment: Não entendi... o que você pretende com isso? Capturar esse conteúdo ou disponibilizar no clip board?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A forma de selecionar os últimos 7 caracteres é simples, e você pode recuperar essa informação de forma simples através do atributo `SelectedText`, como no exemplo abaixo.

```
var numeroDeCaracteres = 7;
var startIndex = textBox1.Text.Length - numeroDeCaracteres;

textBox1.SelectionStart = startIndex;
textBox1.SelectionLength = numeroDeCaracteres;
```

Mas esse tipo de operação é mais comum para manipulação de interface ou se você quiser por exemplo lançar esse conteúdo no clipbard, recortar e ou colar em algum outro controle... se o que lhe interessa o conteúdo, faz mais sentido apenas um Substring do Text...

```
var numeroDeCaracteres = 7;
var startIndex = textBox1.Text.Length - numeroDeCaracteres;
var conteudo = textBox1.Text.Substring(startIndex);
```

Comment: Perfeito! A ideia é usar parte do conteúdo do textBox (no caso os ultimos 7 caracteres) como variável de nome para um arquivo de imagem. Acho que o primeiro método funciona melhor no meu código pois uso "textBox1.SelecectedText" como output. Irei fazer o teste das duas e depois digo qual funcionou melhor. Muito obrigado Leandro!

Comment: Testado e aprovado! Ambos os métodos funcionaram perfeitamente, mas preferi usar o primeiro pois não precisou de nenhuma outra modificação no meu código. Mais uma vez meus sinceros agradecimentos ao Leandro! Valeuu!

Comment: Recomendo a segunda opção, você não vai precisar mudar tanta coisa e o que mudar vai ser pra melhor. Ela faz muito mais sentido...